# Update made my speakers disappear

Tags: audio, speakers, headphones, bose

I have a pair of bose speakers that are just simply plugged into the headphone jack and have worked perfectly for 7 years. Windows update comes through and suddenly my speakers don't appear on the sound icon in the taskbar. Just my monitors and headset appear. I checked in device manager and they showed there with an error symbol until i clicked "update drivers" then the installation failed and the speakers disappeared forever. Restarted loads, updated realtek drivers, nothing is working, please help!
Every guide online seems to be for complete newbies and I can't find anyone who's had this problem online.
Edit: I updated IDT drivers and they showed up for a second or two during installation but then disappeared and aren't there after the restart.

Comment: Adding your Operating system would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

What you can possibly do is that you can plug out your speaker and delete the drivers in the device manager. Just in case, restart the computer and connect the speakers to the computer. I think it will scan for the new device and download drivers for it. It should work out now.

Hope it helps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion, but jsut about didn't have to resort to that. After the IDT update, the driver reappeared in decive manager and I followed these steps.
https://www.auslogics.com/en/articles/fix-idt-high-definition-audio-codec/

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: So, did this solve your problem?  Honestly, this whole thing sounds silly.. there ARE NO DEVICE DRIVERS for something plugged into a headphone jack but the headphone jack can have a trigger to determine if the audio should go through the speakers or jack.